# Open fragment with button from another fragment

Tags: java, android

I want to open another fragment using a button from another fragment.

This is the fragment with the button

```
 @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myday, container, false);
        Button buttonNext = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.next);
        buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment someFragment = new TomorrowFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fr.replace(R.id.fragment_container, someFragment);
                fr.commit();

            }
        });

        return view;
```

Fragment xml

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next to 2"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/next"/>
```

after I press the button nothing happens. I have followed code from other posts but nothing worked..

Answer (score 0):

```
buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment someFragment = new TomorrowFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fr = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fr.replace(R.id.fragment_container, someFragment);
                fr.commitAllowingStateLoss();

            }
        });
```

Comment: what does it mean ? the commitAllowingStateLoss() ? I was planning on making all my fragments to not lose their state (the data ) when switching between them. Will this go against it ? @khushpreet

Comment: It will work fine , If you want to keep your data saved during fragment transaction,then use add instead of replace.